# ¿existe algun metodo que devuelva un array con los valores de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, jsonarray

Tengo este objeto JSON:

```
{
 "Curso": "Basico",
 "Integrantes": [
   {
   "Nombre": "Marlon",
   "Edad": 26 
  }, {
   "Nombre": "Marcos",
   "Edad": 28
  }, {
   "Nombre": "Adan",
   "Edad": 23 
  },
]}
```

Queria saber como puedo hacer para sumar el valor de las edades en los objetos. Ayudenme por favor, es solo un ejemplo pero la logica la necesito para mi tesis de grado.

Comment: @BetaM En serio estoy desesperado, lo necesito para mi tesis. No es momento de eso

Comment: @BetaM quiero acceder a la propiedad Edad de los objetos que almacena el array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le recomiendo que uses la funcion **`reduce`** la cual basicamente itera por cada uno de los elementos de un array y le aplica un funcion acumulativa

```
data.Integrantes.reduce((acc, i)=>acc + i.Edad, 0);
```

donde:

- acc=>acumulado de las sumas de las edades en este caso.
- i  => elemento actual del array que se esta iterando

por lo tanto esta linea de codigo suma las edades de todos los integrantes, a continuacion en ejemplo funcional.

```js
const data = {
 "Curso": "Basico",
 "Integrantes": [
   {
   "Nombre": "Marlon",
   "Edad": 26 
  }, {
   "Nombre": "Marcos",
   "Edad": 28
  }, {
   "Nombre": "Adan",
   "Edad": 23 
  },
]};
const result = data.Integrantes.reduce((acc, i)=>acc+i.Edad,0);
$("#resultado").text(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<H1>Para este objeto</H1>
<code>
{
 "Curso": "Basico",
 "Integrantes": [
   {
   "Nombre": "Marlon",
   "Edad": 26 
  }, {
   "Nombre": "Marcos",
   "Edad": 28
  }, {
   "Nombre": "Adan",
   "Edad": 23 
  },
]}
</code>
<p>
La suma de las edades es <span id="resultado">???</span></p>
```

Comment: @BetaM Disculpa amigo, no es una tarea, es una duda que me tiene paralizada mi tesis de grado, no tengo casi tiempo de internet, por eso no pude desarrollar mucho la pregunta. De todos modos gracias por tu intento de ayudarme. Pareciera que te interesa mas las "reglas burocraticas" que ayudar a los demas, que es para lo cual existe la comunidad en primer lugar. Saludos

Comment: @BetaM un ejercio de tarea para una tesis puede ser tan importante y definitivo para una persona como lo puede ser para un producto comercial, de hecho creo en mi modesta opinion que es mas importante ayudar a los que estan aprendiendo ahora, por lo annos que llevo con SO es primera vez que veo una votacion negativa por esta razon, que la pregunta necesita ser editada y mejorada estoy de acuerdo, pero mi respuesta no es negativa me parece acertada y productiva, con todo el respeto a su votacion, en la creo que deberia reflexionar

Comment: @RonierRamos tiene alguna duda con mi respuesta, le ha sido util?

Comment: @cyberdantes Gracias por ayudarme amigo.

Comment: @cyberdantes Tu respuesta era lo que buscaba. Muchisimas gracias. Habia intentado varias soluciones pero ya me daba por vencido. Por eso vine aca. Gracias mil

Comment: @RonierRamos ahora solo marca la respuesta como la solucion que tu escojes como correcta y de esa manera sera util para quien en el futuro haga esta misma pregunta, en el futuro lo editores y moderadores del sitio quizas mejoren el enfoque de tu pregunta y lo hagan mas a la manera de esta version en espannol de Stack overflow

Comment: La verdad prefiero mil veces romperme la cabeza con algo que pepdir ayuda, para evitarme comentarios como esos.

Comment: @RonierRamos al margen de todo creo que siempre es muy bueno consultar a otros mas alla de las experiencias +- agradables que tengas, lo importantes es que avances en tu proyecto y que la cominudad de OP tenga mas contenido, entre todos podemos mejorar esta pregunta, que necesita que la marques como ya respondiday eso solo lo puedes hacer tu, para que ayudes a los que despues de ti tengan el mismo problema y regresen aqui a la misma consulta